# PostgreSQL 10, PgAdmin

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Есть ли возможность в PostgreSQL импортировать csv файл без создание columns. Просто бывает один csv имеет более 200-300 название столбцов и создавать это трудоемко. Например SQLite сам же автоматическом режиме импортирует. Если что то подобное есть прошу поделиться. Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Автоматически - нет такого. Хотя бы из-за более строгой типизации. Читай файл во временную таблицу (вся строка файла в одно текстовое поле), затем по содержимому первой строки определяй имена полей, динамическим SQL создавай структуру, другим динамическим SQL парси и раскладывай по полям остальные строки (или заново выполняй копирование, но уже в существующую структуру). Затем, если надо, определяй наиболее подходящий тип данных для каждого поля и вноси соотв. изменения в структуру. В общем, пиши свою процедуру импорта.

Comment: Принято! спасибо! попробую так